# How to used php insert data to Azure custom log

Tags: php, azure

I want to insert data to Azure custom log but now i create custom log and set collection paths to C:\Logs*.txt. This is my first time for this thing and i spend my time for 4 days to do this but now i have noting. I need your help please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [HTTP Data Collector API (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api).

> This article shows you how to use the HTTP Data Collector API to send log data to Azure Monitor from a REST API client. It describes how to format data that's collected by your script or application, include it in a request, and have that request authorized by Azure Monitor. We provide examples for Azure PowerShell, C#, and Python

> URI: https://.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=2016-04-01

Request body:

```json
[
    {
        "property 1": "value1",
        "property 2": "value2",
        "property 3": "value3",
        "property 4": "value4"
    }
]
```

Comment: How can i get CustomerId  and SharedKey?
I 'm not owner of azure account something i don't have permission to do.
Do i have to setting someting before doing this.

Comment: "To authenticate a request, sign the request with either the primary or the secondary key for the workspace that's making the request. Then, pass that signature as part of the request." well, if you want to use Azure resources, you need access to it. Or at least you need to know someone who has access and can provide you with the required information.